# The degree of mapping between compact surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\boldsymbol{F} :~M~\rightarrow~N$ be a (regular) mapping between compact, oriented surfaces (two dimensional Riemannian manifolds).

The degree $d_{\boldsymbol{F}}$ of $\boldsymbol{F}$ is defined by

$d_{\boldsymbol{F}}$=$\displaystyle \frac{\int_{M} \boldsymbol{F}^* dN}{\int_{N} dN}$ where $dN$ is an area form of the surface $N$.

Now, I have a general question for $d_{\boldsymbol{F}}$.

When $M \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ and $\boldsymbol{F}$ is a Gauss map, $d_{\boldsymbol{F}}$ is an integer by the direct application of the Gauss-Bonnet theorem.

However, I don't know $d_{\boldsymbol{F}}$ is integer generally. 
I think this is different with the sense of the vector field.

Comment: It's always an integer. For a reasonably elementary proof, you'll need to learn a little bit of differential topology by reading Guillemin and Pollack. They call this "definition" the Degree Formula and prove it on pp. 188-191. (Of course, there is a differential-topological definition of degree given by counting preimage points of a(ny) regular value, with sign.)

Comment: @TedShifrin/ Can we prove above fact without using the differential topology? Maybe I have to explain this fact to undergraduate students.

Comment: This is not a simple matter. Do you know that every $2$-form on $N$ differs from some multiple of the area form by an exact form? [In terms of deRham cohomology, this is the statement that $H^2_{\text{deRham}}(N)\cong\Bbb R$.]